# Haskell extract hostname from URLType

Tags: haskell, monads, option-type

I'm using [Network.URL](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/url-2.1.3/docs/Network-URL.html) and importing a URL from a String:

```
url_type $ fromJust $ importURL "https://google.com/"
Absolute (Host {protocol = HTTP True, host = "google.com", port = Nothing})
```

Now to get the host I can pattern match and use the host function:

```
url' :: URLType -> Host
url' (Absolute host) = host

host $ url' $ url_type $ fromJust $ importURL "https://google.com"
```

That certainly would work, but URLType is defined as:

```
data URLType
  = Absolute Host
  | HostRelative
  | PathRelative
```

In the `url'` function, only `Absolute Host` is taking into consideration, and it'll fail if the url is `HostRelative` or `PathRelative`. How can I make a `url'` function to extract the host whether given or not?

Comment: A `HostRelative` has no host, this is typically if you for example have a link to `/foo`, where the host is thus taken from the previous link.

Comment: So, can I just infer the URL will always contain a hostname and leave the function as it is?

Comment: no, a URL can contain a hostname if it is an `Absolute`, otherwise the url has *no* hostname, and you thus can not "obtain" one. You can make a function that returns a `Maybe Host`, and thus maps `(Absolute host) = Just host`, and the other ones to `Nothing`.

Comment: Something like this `url' :: URLType -> Maybe Host
url' (Absolute host) = Just host
url' HostRelative = Nothing
url' PathRelative = Nothing` and then use `fromJust` to get the host?

Comment: no, not `fromJust`, the idea of using a `Maybe` is that it is possible that there is *no* host, so it basically represents a "computation that can fail".

Comment: Something like pattern matching on `Just` and `Nothing` and invoking `host` if `Just host` and/or returning an empty string if Nothing? `hostname :: Maybe Host -> String
hostname host' = case host' of Just host' -> host host'
                               Nothing    -> ""`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Original answer

I think all you need is making your `url'` a monadic function which returns a `Maybe Host`, composing `url_type` with `return` to make another monadic function which returns a `Monad` (which in this specific use happens to be a `Maybe` too), and then making a monadic chain using the `>>=` operator:

```hs
import Network.URL
import Data.Maybe (fromJust)

url' :: URLType -> Maybe Host
url' (Absolute host) = Just host
url' _ = Nothing

output :: Maybe Host
output = importURL "https://google.com" >>= return . url_type >>= url'
```

Notice that `output` is a `Maybe Host`. You cannot get a `Host` if you accept that the whole operation can fail. If you can assume the operation cannot fail, then you're ok with `fromJust`, but you would be asking the question, if this was the case, I believe.

### Improvement

In a comment is pointed out that `>> return . url_type` is bit gross. I'm new to Haskell, so I basically wrote the first thing that came to my mind.  And probably I chose a monadic style because I've been playing with and looking at example of monads more than applicatives. Plus, I'm still to new to Haskell to comfortably use functorial, applicative, and monadic styles together: I just didn't think of writing the expression as suggested in the comment, as mine looked ok to me. Below I "reintepret" the comment based on my knowledge.

What is a bit ugly is the part `importURL "https://google.com" >>= return . url_type`, because the operator `>>=`, whose type is in general `Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`, is "forcing" its second argument to return a `Monad`, even though the "wannabe" second argument `url_type` doesn't, thus forcing us to compose it with `return` in order to honor the `a -> m b` part of the signature. What we would really prefer, is to sent `url_type` inside the monad provided by `importURL "bla"`, operate on that inside, and leave the result there, inside the monad; i.e. we would in fact just use `importURL "bla"` as `Functor` (which it is, because it is a `Monad`). So how do we do it? We do so by means of `fmap`:

```hs
output = (fmap url_type $ importURL "https://google.com") >>= url'
```

where I had to use `$` to prevent `fmap` from eagerly swallowing `importURL`, thus leaving the string alone. We've not finished yet: `fmap` has an infix equivalent, `<$>` (notice that `$` and `<$>` have nothing to do with each other), so we can rewrite the above as

```hs
output = url_type <$> importURL "https://google.com" >>= url'
```

At this point, I'd say, we have an expression which is even uglier than before, with the input in the middle of it. But `=<<` to the resque. It is essentially `flip (>>=)`, so we can flip the two operands, thus obtaining the expression that was suggested in the comment:

```hs
output = url' =<< url_type <$> importURL "https://google.com"
```

Comment: `>>= return . f` is a bit gross. I'd suggest something like `url' =<< url_type <$> importURL "https://google.com"`. The refactoring to `<$>` is the main thing, but I also like to advertise `=<<` instead of `>>=`, since it nicely has the same reading order as the monad-less operation `url' . url_type . importURL $ "https://google.com"`

Comment: @amalloy, thank you for the suggestion. I've taking the change to improve my answer by guiding the reader from my gross version to yours, following (I hope) a reasonable series of edits.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to update the answer after the comments. There's a lot to learn here.

Comment: @KarolKarol, happy the hear that :)